# Does C language specify any implicit initialization for void pointers only?

Tags: c, initialization, void-pointers

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int *p;
    void *x;
    printf("%p\n", p);
    printf("%p\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

which will print:

> koraytugay$ ./a.out 
>  0x7fff53b35ad0
>  0x0
>  koraytugay$
>   ./a.out 
>  0x7fff5803fad0
>  0x0
>  koraytugay$ ./a.out 
>   0x7fff512c9ad0
>  0x0
>  koraytugay$ ./a.out 
>  0x7fff55213ad0
>   0x0
>  koraytugay$ ./a.out 
>  0x7fff52dbdad0
>  0x0

Is there any explanation to this behaviour in the language?

Comment: `p` and `x` are uninitialized variables and standard says using uninitialized variables leads to undefined behavior. The code doesn't make any sense printing out uninitialized variables

Comment: Nope. No explanation with definition. Your code invokes undefined behavior. You're evaluating *indeterminate* variables in *both* cases.

Comment: Is undefined behaviour. What's your question?

Comment: @WhozCraig Are you sure indeterminate values cause UB in C (as opposed to C++)?

Comment: I don't think that it invokes an undefined behavior, just that the values are indeterminate by the standard. The implementations, however, may just extend the standard and still be standard-compliant. Uninitialized local variables, for example, in MacOS always zeroed out (as far as I remember, for security reasons), and may deceive you into thinking that this is just a general fact. It is not. It only happens to be so in MacOS.

Comment: OK, N1570 6.3.2.1/p2. [This](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined) is a fun read.

Comment: @Koray I edited the question title to make it more suitable. Is that ok with you?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sure, it is just a question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, the `C11` standard is quite clear in this regard. Referring chapter 6.7.9, paragraph 10,

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

Now, an *indeterminate* value is , well, *indeterminate* (which you're referring to as garbage and / or NULL here). You cannot really know what is going to be there.

---

EDIT:

Just to clarify, as per the comment,

> > *"But the `void *p` seems to be NULL always"*

Right. It **seems**. It's nothing guaranteed (specified), as far as `C` standard is considered.

<sup>Just a note: Prefer `int main(void)` over `int main()`. The former is recommended.</sup>

Comment: But the void *p seems to be NULL always.

Comment: @KorayTugay maybe, but C does not say anything about that. Maybe a compiler extension (just guessing).

Comment: Indeterminate means, you *cannot depend on it*, not random. It depends on the compiler.

Comment: Well anyway thanks for the answer, it seems people get a bit mad when you ask "simple" questions :)

Comment: @KorayTugay well, sometime, sadly, yes.

Answer (score 6):

You asked:

> In C, why is a void pointer NULL by declaration but other types contain garbage?

That is an erroneous conclusion using a small program. Uninitialized pointers in function scope get random values. You cannot rely on any pattern in their values.

Comment: @KorayTugay well it happens in your system with your program doesn't mean that it'll always happen in any cases, any systems, with any compilers

Comment: @KorayTugay Reorder your print statements - depending on your environment, you might then get the impression "that int pointers are always NULL" (which they are not, they are simply **uninitialized**)

Comment: @KorayTugay That is what UB is about. On my system, after I exchange the two print lines, printing `p` results in NULL.

Comment: @KorayTugay You are looking at one tree and concluding that all trees in all forests in all countries are the same.

Comment: @AlanAu Well actually I am asking other foresters about an observation I made to get answers from experienced people instead of go look for 12341 more trees.

Comment: @KorayTugay Those experienced people have given you the answer. But you keep saying "but it's not the case on *my* system".

Comment: @KorayTugay if you reverse the sequence of the two pointer definitions you'll still get the same program output, showing that a `void*` is not initialised to `NULL`. As a local variable, it's not  inintialised unless *you* do so.

Comment: @WeatherVane For me even if I reverse the sequence, output is same.